# Is there any quantum gate that can change quantum hardware topology(architecture)?

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization, architecture

I read about this paper
[Hardware-aware Heuristic for the Qubit Mapping problem in the NISQ Era](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9205650).
I wonder there is the only SWAP gate that can change the quantum hardware topology.
Is there any gates that can change it except Bridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say that swap gate changes a topology of a quantum processor as this is given by physical properties of the processor, mainly conectivity among qubits.

Swap gate simply switch content of two qubits to overcome non-full connectivity among qubits, hardware topology remains intact. I can imagine that it is possible to group physical qubits into logical ones and in the end you could have full connectivity among these logical qubits but at the hardware level, the topology is again given.

To come back to the original question. As far as I know only swap and bridge gates are used for adapting a quantum circuit to the topology of the quantum processor.